# composer install pear package

Tags: php, pear, composer-php, package-managers, phpseclib

I know you can install packages from [any pear channel](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#pear), and I have this working on a basic pear package

```
...
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "pear",
        "url": "http://pear.php.net"
    }
],
"require-dev": {
    "pear-pear/Mail": "*"
}
...
```

What I'm trying to do is install a dependency for testing from a different channel.

```
sudo pear channel-discover phpseclib.sourceforge.net
sudo pear install phpseclib/Net_SSH2
```

I've tried just about every config combination that I can think of in my composer.json to get this package to install, but it never seems to find anything or work.

**What is the correct way/configuration, in my composer.json, to get this package to install?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not sure if this is the correct way, but I got it working w/ the following config.

```
...
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "pear",
        "url": "http://pear.php.net"
    },
    {
        "type": "pear",
        "url": "http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net",
        "vendor-alias": "phpseclib"
    }
],
"require-dev": {
    "pear-pear/Mail": "*",
    "phpseclib/Net_SSH2": "*"
}
...
```

Comment: I didn't know you could install PEAR packages via composer lol. That said you shouldn't need to with phpseclib as phpseclib has an entry at packagist.org.